# How to set fulfillmentText from a value taken from an API call using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, axios

I was able to retrieve data using axios but I can't seem to publish it to `fulfillmentText` of `dialogflow`:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        return await fetch.get(url)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
   
const countBreeds = async () => {
    const breeds = await getData();
}
   
responseJson.fulfillmentText = countBreeds().body;
}
```

Comment: Show your full code, are you using webhooks?.

Answer (score 0):

moved

```
responseJson.fulfillmentText = countBreeds().body;
```

right after

```
const breeds = await getData();
```

and it should be

```
responseJson.fulfillmentText  = breeds.data.body;
```